# The TensorFlow Objet Detection Analysis results of the evaluation of a model (API Evaluation Metrics)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I created a dataset of approximately 200 flower images to detect the dead part of a flower. I used `tensorflow-lite` and the AI pretrained model `EfficientDet-lite2` to train my model. I tested it with a Raspberry Pi camera and it detected the desired object very well with a good percentage of precision. But when I started the model evaluation with the command `model.evaluate_tflite('model.tflite', test_data)`, the results for the precision and the recall of the model were not in conformity with what I expected to obtain. Would it be possible to explain to me the exact nature of his results? I do not understand them.

```
{'AP': 0.14099188,
 'AP50': 0.22554603,
 'AP75': 0.11386139,
 'AP_/Dead-Part': 0.14099188,
 'APl': 0.47425744,
 'Apm': 0.08490314,
 'APs': 0.000558652,
 'ARl': 0.6,
 'ARm': 0.175,
 'ARmax1':0.11818182,
 'ARmax10': 0.2,
 'ARmax100': 0.24545455,
 'ARs': 0.1}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the exact nature of his results"?

Comment: What exactly does each value represent, would there be documentation to understand and interpret the results

Comment: moreover, would there be documentation or other websites to help diagnose the model and these results?